# Google sheets sum of arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I want to use arrayformula or filter like with the result of a list of numbers. My question is how to place at the bottom a total of the preceding numbers. The challenge is this is dynamically sized. So when I try to include an option to sum the numbers it doesn't work.

What complicates this even further I would then want to include some numbers below this that aren't included in the sum.
What I tried was this:

```
={"title"; ArrayFormula; sum of previous cells}
```

| Projects | Title |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | 1 |
| P2 | 2 |
| P3 | 1 |
| P4 | 2 |
| Total | **6** |

Edit: An example that I've used that didn't work out is this:

```
={arrayformula(if(filter($A2:$A,$A2:A<>"",$A2:$A<>"Total Sum",$A2:$A<>"(to be hired)")="","",{countifs('org 1'!$F$2:$F$1000),"="&filter($A2:$A,$A2:$A<>""),'org 1'!$A$2:$A$1000"),"<>(to be hired)")}));"Total hired"}
```

Edit:
Here's an example link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iBkX1B53vYQVUJ6j8dNOE_ck1dONidsqyNuO0lgSKHw/edit?usp=sharing
I'm using multiple tabs as a reflection to what I'm working with. The tab everything's suppose to show is the Indirect example tab.

I'm using the Source tab as a reference for the tabs I'm targeting. The data tabs is the place I'm drawing the info from.

I'm thinking that I won't be able to do this with ArrayFormula. Probably with Query instead. Not sure what it would look like. If ArrayFormula won't work then a query example would be nice.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: I wish I could, I have to use a monitored computer instead of the computer I normally work on. I can't copy the data off that one.

Comment: here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10MrYskHXKEwU2tZuPFW98LMXwzxVP8quBKePiKKMmNI/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Kaws Create a sample gs and put some dummy data then share that gs here.

Answer (score 1):

see:

```
={"title"; FILTER(A:A, A:A<>""); SUM(A:A)}
```

[image]

---

```
={QUERY({A1:B}, "where Col1 is not null label Col2'title'"); "Total:", SUM(B:B)}
```

[image]

Comment: I've found this answer before. The problem is this relies on the source data instead of something like sum(D2:D). After looking at the problem, I think my answer might be to get the list and sum the list both from the source instead of having the sum calculated by loading the list and then calculating from that list.


I kind of wanted to make a query then add a total at the bottom of that. I feel like I should look at using a query instead.